# enabling ssl connection from wordpress to mysql

Tags: ssl, wordpress, mysql5.5, php56

I have been searching on how to configure wordpress to connect to mysql db over ssl, however most of the example are about three to five years old e.g. [this wordpress support topic](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-with-mysql-over-ssl)

my wordpress version is 4.5.2 and obviusly the code and settings is nothing like what I in examples all over forums, is there a more relevant example on how to fix settings in `wp-settings.php` and `wp-includes/wp-db.php` to ensure secure connection to a remote MySql?

Comment: It seems to me like overkill to add an SSL layer on each database call.  You'll regret it too soon to spend five more minutes on solving it this way.  A much better solution would be to setup a VPN connection between both servers.  This way, the MySQL connection is secured by directing it through the VPN, and all operations go much faster.

Comment: @JuliePelletier the SSL handshake delay can be avoided by using persistent connections.But this cannot be done with some PHP setups, ie. using CGI SAPI.

Comment: It's about trade offs, between moving parts of VPN & tunnels etc, and SSL, I would like to go with the latter :-)

Comment: I'm curious what is so criticial in your Wordpress install it needs SSL, and why you're using an untrusted network? This is a valid pattern for enterprise apps in shared data centers where confidential information is in play, but is overkill for many situations.

Comment: I am on cloud hosting, can't keep all eggs in single basket, we have PIIs in the database, hence the SSL part

Answer (score 9):

Edit `wp-config.php`

Add following line:

```
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

If your database(MySQL 5.6 or later) use a self-assigned certificate, you may try:

```
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);
```

Tested on WordPress version `5.2`.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a way to do this w/o hacking core or rolling your own plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/secure-db-connection/

Created by the dev who initially reported the issue in WordPress:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28625

Answer (score 0):

here the solution: you have to add the ssl cert in a bin folder, then refer to the server with a variable
[https://atiqcs.wordpress.com/2018/07/22/enable-ssl-with-azure-web-app-for-mysql-database/#:~:text=Enabling%20SSL%20with%20Azure%20Web%20App%20for%20mysql,MySQL%20over%20SSL%20below%20mentions%20adding%20DB_SSL%2C%20](https://atiqcs.wordpress.com/2018/07/22/enable-ssl-with-azure-web-app-for-mysql-database/#:%7E:text=Enabling%20SSL%20with%20Azure%20Web%20App%20for%20mysql,MySQL%20over%20SSL%20below%20mentions%20adding%20DB_SSL%2C%20)

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure this is answered best [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850112/using-amazon-rds-with-wordpress-over-ssl#answer-29995596) you basically add a filter, and the details to the SSL certificate details in `wp-config.php`

There is also a plugin on the wordpress.org repository [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/secure-db-connection/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should duplicate content that may change based upon third-party decision making simply to boost StackOverflow keywords? I was merely trying to provide an answer that stood the test of time; feel free to make the edits you desire but the downvote and needlessly pedantic comment are not appreciated

Comment: Yes, that's what @JennyD is saying. Link-only answers become useless when the original content moves of goes away.

Comment: I'm sorry but that ignores fundamentals of the web, such as being able to use archive.org, or the documentation author simply updating their links. I absolutely accept that if someone links to my personal site dead links may be a factor. If I link to MySQL 5.5 docs, or latest, it's less likely the URL will be broken than the duplicate content obsolete. You're arguing to create a network graph problem.

Comment: Put in a simpler way, if the link breaks there is one place to change it (on the site of the link). If SO answer + quora + every other platform has a change then there are N places to change that content.